# How to make Windows Service start as "Automatic (Delayed Start)"

Tags: c#, windows-services, wcf

**Scenario:**

A WCF service running as a Windows Service. Account is "User".

---

**What is done:**

I have overridden the OnBeforeInstall in the projectinstaller to be able to set username and password from a config file.

---

**What I would be able to do:**

I'd like to be able to set the starttype as Automatic (Delayed Start)

---

**What I have tried:**

I put the following coderow in the overridden OnBeforeInstall

`serviceInstaller1.StartType = ServiceStartMode.Automatic + 1;`

Figured I would trick the ServiceStartMode enum into representing Automatic (Delayed Start), didn't work. Haven't tried anything more simply because I couldn't find anything to try.

---

**What I have found on the net:**

I found out that Automatic (Delayed Start) will be available in .NET 4, but that doesn't help me right now.
[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.serviceinstaller.delayedautostart%28VS.100%29.aspx)
I found out that DelayedAutoStart could be added to the service's configuration key, but this feels like a hack if I should do this from code. But maybe this is the only solution available for me at this point?

- [WS2008: Startup Processes and Delayed Automatic Start](http://blogs.technet.com/askperf/archive/2008/02/02/ws2008-startup-processes-and-delayed-automatic-start.aspx)

*Any ideas?*

Robert Persson, Sweden

Answer (score 44):

Now that .NET 4.0 is here:

```
serviceInstaller1.StartType = ServiceStartMode.Automatic;
serviceInstaller1.DelayedAutoStart = true;
```

Comment: Does anyone know where this code gets added? ServiceInstaller.cs? In the constructor for the ServiceInstaller()? In the constructor for the service?

Comment: I have it in my ProjectInstaller.Designer.cs file along with the credentials, etc.

Answer (score 6):

Your only other option is to use P/invoke to call [ChangeServiceConfig2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681988%28VS.85%29.aspx) with `SERVICE_CONFIG_DELAYED_AUTO_START_INFO`. But since you seem to be unwilling to add the registry entry, I doubt you would want to use P/invoke. There's no other way to do it from the .NET Framework (< 4.0).

Comment: Thanks!

The contractor wanted the service to have Automatic (Start Delayed) if it was possible, but it wasn't crucial. So we'll wait until .NET 4.

Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 5):

For my .NET Framework 3.5 project, I can install my service as an "Automatic (Delayed)" service by manually setting the `DelayedAutostart` value for my service. For example:

```
public ProjectInstaller()
{
  ...

  AfterInstall += ProjectInstaller_AfterInstall;
}

void ProjectInstaller_AfterInstall(object sender, InstallEventArgs e)
{
  string serviceName = <YourSpecific>Installer.ServiceName;

  using (RegistryKey serviceKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"System\CurrentControlSet\Services\" + serviceName, true))
  {
      serviceKey.SetValue("DelayedAutostart", 1, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
  }
}
```

Note that after you install the service, the service will not be listed as "Automatic (Delayed)" until **after the computer is restarted**.

Comment: Thanks for the hint about the restart. I was getting mad looking for reasons why it didn't worked when as far as I could see the registry keys were there.

Comment: Hello jdknight, Is it mandatory to changes registry settings for "Automatic (Delayed Start)" ?

Comment: For .NET 3.5 it is. If you're using a new framework, refer to [fiat's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9525289/693291).

Answer (score 1):

I'll expand on jdknight answer a little bit. I had writting permission issues while attempting his solution, so here's what I did:

```
void ProjectInstaller_AfterInstall(object sender, InstallEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("System", true); //Opens the System hive with writting permissions set to true
        key = key.CreateSubKey("CurrentControlSet"); //CreateSubKey opens if subkey exists, otherwise it will create that subkey
        key = key.CreateSubKey("services");
        key = key.CreateSubKey(serviceInstaller1.ServiceName);
        key.SetValue("DelayedAutostart", 1, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(exc.Message);
    }
}
```

I also registered to the AfterInstall event by adding a new instance of InstallEventHandler. I'm not sure if that's actually necessary, but it won't hurt either:

```
AfterInstall += new InstallEventHandler(ProjectInstaller_AfterInstall);
```

Works like a charm on .NET Framework 2.0. As it has been pointed out before, for frameworks 4 and above, use

```
serviceInstaller1.DelayedAutoStart = true;
```

according to fiat's answer.