# Detect that Windows is "fully-running"

Tags: windows, startup

For programming matters, I would need to detect when Windows is "fully-running", i.e. all the startup programs are running and Windows is in kind of "waiting-for-instruction mode". Is there any way to detect it ?

Comment: I think it's just before you hit the power-off button.  (The problem is that, even after Windows is "up", it may be another 15 minutes before it stops thrashing to the extent that work can be done.)

Comment: Many services and programs run on-demand and not automatically when Windows "starts up". It would be very helpful if you explained what your goal is, and why you think that waiting until "all the startup programs are running" will help you.

Comment: Did you mean like [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13756/Detecting-Application-Idleness)?

Comment: @GSerg : this should be an answer (which would be accepted) and not a comment ;)

Comment: @NNzz Nah, link-only answers are discouraged on SO.

Comment: Imagine if there were two such programs. Each one would wait indefinitely for the other one to finish starting up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install a service with delayed start, that is usually enough time to wait:

[How to make Windows Service start as "Automatic (Delayed Start)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2153490/how-to-make-windows-service-start-as-automatic-delayed-start)

or if you want to make sure the computer is actually idle, the answer posted in the comment by GSerg is correct:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13756/Detecting-Application-Idleness