# Install Service As Delayed Automatic

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, service, registry, windows-installer

I have a service coded in c# .NET 3.5 being installed using a Visual Studio 2010 installer. I need the service to be set up as Automatic Delayed start. I have found some articles which tell me to set the Service to Automatic, and then add a DWORD to the Registry at `HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\theservice`. The problem is that I'm not quite sure how to add the Registry key using my installer.

[One site](http://metah.ch/blog/2012/09/how-to-change-a-service-startup-type-with-powershell/) I visited suggested this script:

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path "Registry::HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\theservice" -Name "DelayedAutostart" -Value 1 -Type DWORD
```

However, I don't see a way to add a post-install event to the installer. [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.install.installer.afterinstall%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) and [jdknight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2153490/how-to-make-windows-service-start-as-automatic-delayed-start) (bottom post) both suggest running a AfterInstall Event, but again I am not quite sure how to incorporate it with the Visual Studio installer.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can't you just the setup project's Registry view to add whatever key and data you need?

Comment: @PhilDW - The Registry View only has structure for the project. I need to access the Services node which does not show up in the Registry view. Thank you for the suggestion, though.

Comment: Right-click HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, then New key, then add SYSTEM, and proceed to add other folders like CurrentControlSet.

Comment: @PhilDW - That did it. I thought New would add the DWORD, not a new node. If you write this up as an answer, I will give credit to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just the setup project's Registry view to add whatever key and data you need?

Note that you can Right-click HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, then New key, then add SYSTEM, and proceed to add other folders like CurrentControlSet.