# How to make Windows service become "Running" when the system boots

Tags: c#, .net, windows, service, windows-services

I know this has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2153490/how-to-make-windows-service-start-as-automatic-delayed-start) but I'm having a more specific issue. I did what was suggested by adding

```
serviceInstaller1.StartType = ServiceStartMode.Automatic;
serviceInstaller1.DelayedAutoStart = true;
```

and indeed I can confirm that after installing I see my service has `Startup Type` equal to `Automatic (Delayed Start)`. However I restarted my machine and it doesn't have `Status` equal to `Running` like other services. I tried without `serviceInstaller1.DelayedAutoStart = true;` and same issue. I'm wondering if my `Log On As` needs to be something other than my domain account. Or what else could be the issue?

Comment: Are you logging errors? Can you confirm it’s attempting to start via the event log? Are you sure your service **can** start successfully?

Comment: Look at the event viewer for errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would check if the service starts with logon = SYSTEM. If that works, in my experience (big enterprise environment), the most common reason is that the user account under which the service is supposed to run does not have the privilege "logon as service". Look in the Windows security event log for logon errors. Depending on your environment you can use use a GPO for enabling this privilege or may set it yourself (via local security policy) if it is allowed in your Windows environment.

Or perhaps your service crashes in OnStart(), but this can also (as Brien and Shetty suppose) normally seen in the event log (application event log).